# SEE EDIT: CSS3 Footer sticks to bottom of the page and left column stretches to the footer

Tags: asp.net, html, css

After nearly six hours of trial and error, I am unable to come up with a solution for my problem - I have built this before, but lack access to old files to see what I did, and have been in a different career path for years now and unfortunately my skill has faded a bit.

I am setting up a website to chronicle my time at sea for work, and it will have:
- a header that is 150px tall and 100% wide
- a nav bar that is 30px tall and 100% wide
- an aside that is 250px wide and stretches fully between the nav bar and footer, regardless of how little content there is in it
- an article div, that will be to the right of the aside that fills the remaining space left over depending on how wide the viewport is
- a footer that is at least to the bottom of the page if the content does not fill the viewport, or if the text flows beyond the limits of the viewport, it will be below that. I do not want an "always visible" footer.

I am using HTML5 and CSS3 along with ASP.net 4.5.

I currently have the header, navigation, and article working the way I want. However, I am not sure how to approach the aside and footer.

I want the footer to be at the bottom of the page. Obviously, if I have a page without much text on it, it will be halfway up the browser screen, and that, as we all know, looks amateur and ridiculous. So I would like it to be at the bottom of the screen, like a normal webpage. And while I am at it, I would also like my aside to fill the 250px wide strip on the left hand of the browser window regardless of how much content is in it too, all the way to the footer so it looks more complete.

Now, as I pointed out, for the last six hours I have been plugging away and have made some serious headway with this, but these two issues I just cant seem to get ironed out. I have used this forum for help, and have exhausted nearly everything without success. Its frustrating to know I have done this numerous times before in just a few minutes, but here I am at 4 am.

Here is the CSS:

```
    * 
{
    margin: 0;
}
body 
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100%;
}

form, html
{
    height: 100%;
}

header
{
    margin: 0px auto; 
    background-color: #1041a2;
    background-image: url(../Images/headerHCJ.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: right;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

#logo
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-image: url(../Images/usmmSeal130.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center; 
}

#title
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 45px;
    padding-left: 150px;
}

#title h1
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}

#title h2
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px black;
}

nav
{
    background-image: url(../Images/nav.png);
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0px auto;

}

#content 
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 100%;
}

aside 
{
    margin: 180px 0px 80px 0px auto;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100%;
}

article
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding-left: 250px;
    min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
    height:80px;
    background: black;
    clear: both;
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
            </div>
            <div id="title">

            </div>
        </header>
        <nav>

        </nav>
        <div id="content">
            <aside>
                Vessel data
            </aside>
            <article>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </article>
        </div>
        <footer>

        </footer>
    </form>
</body>
```

Thank you all so much for your feedback.

EDIT: I am very close to a solution. I have modified my code so that the aside and article are contained in a div, and set the aside to min-height of 100%, after making changes to the form, html, and body elements. It now is expanded to 100 percent of the viewport, with one problem. It LITERALLY is 100% the height of the viewport RATHER than 100% of the height of the container div. The header/nav bar occupy 180px at the top of the page, and the footer occupies 80px at the bottom. The page will scroll 240 px regardless of the size of the viewport. My initial fix for that was to add margin: 180px 0px 80px 0px auto. This however, did not solve the problem. Code above is edited to reflect changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rplute/8FD6X/1/).

Inspiration was from this [article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/) on css-tricks.com.

Basic concept (HTML)

```
<div class="content">
    Content
</div>
<footer>
    I'm a footer
</footer>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
      height: 100%;
}
#content {
      min-height: 100%;
      /* equal to footer height */
      margin-bottom: -80px; 
}
#content:after {
     content: "";
     display: block;
}
footer, #content:after {
     /* .push must be the same height as footer */
    height: 80px; 
 }
 footer {
    background: black;
}
```

For the container in the jsFiddle itself, I put

```
display: inline-block;
```

and for the aside element with the left class, I put

```
float: left;
```

and left the article element with the right class untouched, so it could expand on width. I also gave them min-height properties in pixels, not percentage so you could see it better visually.

Comment: Hey Justin, I looked at your jsfiddle and applied those exact parameters (minus the fixed values in place of the percentages used by the actual application you used for demonstration purposes) and the footer seems to hover (e.g. there is white space I can scroll to further below it). The article text now wraps around the aside, which is opposite of what I need, and the aside does not extend fully from nav bar to footer. I will look further into your example to ensure I didn't miss anything. I appreciate your efforts greatly.

Comment: I marked this as the answer after further review of the code. The basics are enough to get the main topic of the question in working order. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Nate, sorry I didn't get to this earlier. I am glad I was of help and thanks for marking it as the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a *fiddle service to demonstrate with your code.  However, you may just need to add the `position: fixed` to your footer.

```
footer {
position: fixed;
height:80px;
background: black;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. My footer has disappeared. Just to clarify, I am using ASP.NET 4.5 if that helps on that side - I know for some things that has an effect but I am unsure if that is also to do with this... Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
header {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/2gX8U/)**

Comment: As with the previous answer, this also made the footer disappear. Thank you for your reply.